# How can i include the company name in my query

Tags: sql, join

I creating a report and need values from the same tables from different companies.

I tried adding information_schema.tables but get stuck on the joins

SQL query I use:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT (Date,GLE.[Posting Date]) AS [Posting date],
    DATEPART (YEAR,GLE.[Posting Date]) AS Year,
    DATEPART (MONTH,GLE.[Posting Date]) AS Month,
    DATEPART (ISOWK,GLE.[Posting Date]) AS Week,
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GLE.[Posting Date]) as Weekday,
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GLE.[Posting Date]) as Weekdayname,
    GLE.[G_L Account No_] AS [G_L account No_],
    GLA.Name AS [G_L account name], 
    GLE.Description AS [Description],
    GLE.[Document No_] AS DocumentNumber,
    GLE.[User ID] AS [User ID],
    CONVERT (DATE, GLE.[Document Date]) AS [Document date],
    GLE.[Source Code] AS [Source code],
    CASE
       WHEN GLE.[Document Type] = '1' THEN 'Payment'
       WHEN GLE.[Document Type] = '2' THEN 'Invoice'
       WHEN GLE.[Document Type] = '3' THEN 'Credit Memo'
       ELSE ' ' 
    END AS [Document type],
    GLE.[VAT Prod_ Posting Group],
    CONVERT(MONEY, GLE.[VAT Amount]) AS [VAT Amount],
    CONVERT(MONEY, GLE.Amount) AS [Amount],
    CASE
       WHEN GLE.[Open] = '0' THEN 'No'
       WHEN GLE.[Open] = '1' THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE ' ' 
    END AS 'Open',
    CONVERT(MONEY, GLE.[Remaining Amount]) AS [Remaining amount],
    CONVERT(DATE, GLE.[Closed at Date]) AS [Closed at date],
    GLE.[External Document No_],
    DSE_BU.[Dimension Value Code] AS BU,
    DSE_PROD.[Dimension Value Code] AS PROD,
    DSE_CC.[Dimension Value Code] AS CC,
    DSE_SL.[Dimension Value Code] AS SL,
    DSE_IC.[Dimension Value Code] AS IC,
    DSE_PROJ.[Dimension Value Code] AS PROJECT
FROM
    [company name$G_L Entry] AS GLE 
INNER JOIN 
    [company name$G_L Account] AS GLA ON GLE.[G_L Account No_] = GLA.No_
LEFT JOIN 
    [company name$Dimension Set Entry] AS DSE_BU ON GLE.[Dimension Set ID] = DSE_BU.[Dimension Set ID] 
                                                 AND DSE_BU.[Dimension Code] = 'BU'
LEFT JOIN 
    [company name$Dimension Set Entry] AS DSE_PROD ON GLE.[Dimension Set ID] = DSE_PROD.[Dimension Set ID] AND DSE_PROD.[Dimension Code] = 'PROD'
LEFT JOIN 
    [company name$Dimension Set Entry] AS DSE_CC ON GLE.[Dimension Set ID] = DSE_CC.[Dimension Set ID] AND DSE_CC.[Dimension Code] = 'CC'
LEFT JOIN 
    [company name$Dimension Set Entry] AS DSE_SL ON GLE.[Dimension Set ID] = DSE_SL.[Dimension Set ID] AND DSE_SL.[Dimension Code] = 'SL'
LEFT JOIN 
    [company name$Dimension Set Entry] AS DSE_IC ON GLE.[Dimension Set ID] = DSE_IC.[Dimension Set ID] AND DSE_IC.[Dimension Code] = 'IC'
LEFT JOIN 
    [company name$Dimension Set Entry] AS DSE_PROJ ON GLE.[Dimension Set ID] = DSE_PROJ.[Dimension Set ID] AND DSE_PROJ.[Dimension Code] = 'PROJECT'
ORDER BY 
    GLE.[G_L Account No_]
```

I expect out come that values per company are shown

Comment: Perhaps posting the sample data for each table and expected output might help us more and you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add a simple window function to your `SELECT`:

```
SUM(CONVERT(MONEY, GLE.Amount)) OVER(PARTITION BY GLE.[G_L Account No_])
```

This will split up the rows into groups by `Account_No` and then add up the `Amount` values within each of those groups.

Assumptions:
1. `GLE.[G_L Account No_]` is the company ID
2. `GLE.Amount` is the amount you want to sum
3. There is a one-to-one relationship between all your joined tables.